# Probability of 3 heads in 4 coin flips

Tags: probability

Forgive me English is not my first language so this is confusing?

Suppose you toss a coin 4 times.
 
a. What is the probability that you will get exactly 3 heads?
b. Explain what P*(not 3 heads) means

*P meaning Probability

Can anyone explain how I would solve this word problem? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  What is the probability that you will get exactly $0$ heads?  What is the probability that you will get exactly one head?  If it helps, there are $2^4$ possibilities for the sequence of four flips.  Try writing them all out and see if you can spot a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

(a) There are four different outcomes that give you exactly $3$ heads: THHH, HTHH, HHTH, and HHHT. The probability of getting exactly $3$ heads is the probability of getting one of these four outcomes, so it is

$$\frac4{\text{number of possible outcomes}};$$

what is the total number of possible outcomes?

(b) You’re tossing four coins, so if you **don’t** get $3$ heads, what are the possible numbers of heads that you could get? $P(\text{not }3\text{ heads})$ is the probability of getting one of these other numbers of heads.

Comment: Thank you! The total number of possible outcomes would be 16, so it would be 4/16 or 1/4?

Comment: @Miki: That’s exactly right.

Comment: @Miki: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there a method of solving this sort of problem without writing out the sample space and counting?

Comment: @radicalmatt: Yes. For the first problem, for example, there are $2^4$ possible outcomes, all equally likely. There are $\binom43$ ways to pick $3$ of the $4$ tosses to be heads, so the probability if $\binom43/2^4=4/16=1/4$.

Answer (score 2):

well by calculating, using the formula $\frac{n!}{s!t!}\times(\frac{1}{2})^s \times (\frac{1}{2})^t$
where $n=$number of tosses s=probability for head
$t=$probability for tail
one gets answer to be $\frac{1}{4}$.
(pretty cool huh)